# Mutex with queue ordered threads

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have a list of threads. The following code releases the mutex lock at the end of the block using the 'with' statement. This is very useful as it allows the user to cycle through each thread and choose to stop it or keep it running.

```
import threading

#subclass with state
class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,myId, astr, mutex):
        self.myId = myId
        self.astr = astr
        self.mutex = mutex
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            with self.mutex:
                print('[%s] => %s' % (self.myId, self.astr))
                ans=raw_input("Enter s to stop thread...")
                if ans == 's':
                    break

stdoutmutex = threading.Lock()
threads = []

for i,j in zip(range(7),['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G']):
    thread = Mythread(i,j,stdoutmutex)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

To ensure the threads are cycled through in the order as found in the 'threads' list, I've used the Queue module to control the order of the thread locks:

```
thread = q.get()
with thread.mutex:
```

The modified script:

```
import threading, Queue

#subclass with state
class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,myId, astr, mutex):
        self.myId = myId
        self.astr = astr
        self.mutex = mutex
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            thread = q.get()
            with thread.mutex:
                print('[%s] => %s' % (self.myId, self.astr))
                ans=raw_input("Enter s to stop thread...")
                if ans == 's':
                    q.task_done()
                    break
                else:
                    q.put(thread)


stdoutmutex = threading.Lock()
threads = []

q = Queue.Queue()

for i,j in zip(range(7),['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G']):
    thread = Mythread(i,j,stdoutmutex)
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    q.put(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

This appears to work as the correct thread order A,B,C... is sent to the standard output. However, can it be verified that the Queue is working and it isn't just a coincidence?

Comment: The code doesn't look correct - there is no guarantee that the first thread will grab the first item.

Comment: I realise `thread.mutex` and `self.mutex` refers to the same thread lock object and that is why the 'thread=q.get()' assignment is not doing anything.